# tableView scroll to bottom doesn't show the last part, have to scroll it manually , does anyone know it?

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

I used the two methodes below, they are both working, but the issue i menttioned.

extension UITableView {

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    let sections = numberOfSections-1
    if sections >= 0 {
        let rows = numberOfRows(inSection: sections)-1
        if rows >= 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows, section: sections)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func moveToLastComment() {
    if self.contentSize.height > self.frame.height {
        let lastSectionIndex = self.numberOfSections - 1 
        let lastRowIndex = self.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1 
        let pathToLastRow = NSIndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: lastSectionIndex)[enter image description here][1]  
        self.scrollToRow(at: pathToLastRow as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height), animated: true)

Comment: with which function are you struggling with? both scrolls fine to the last cell. Could you attach some `gif` explaining your problem more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
 self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFLOAT_MAX), animated: true)
```